# Why my buttons OnClick event fails to fire?

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have an activity, where the ListView holds customized linear layout elements for each row. One of the rows has a button defined as:

```
 <Button
            android:text="Pick a contact"
            android:id="@+id/btnPickContact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
```

Then in java, I have this code:

```
((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnPickContact)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ONLINE_ID, (String)v.getTag(TAG_ONLINE_ID));
                    act.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
                }
            });
```

In this setup the event fails to start.

Also I've tried by implementing the interface:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ONLINE_ID, (String)v.getTag(TAG_ONLINE_ID));
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }
```

still no luck, the event doesn't fire.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the xml defining the button you need to specify a handler using onclick="somehandler". And in your activity have

```
public someHandler(View v) {
}
```

v will be the button.

Comment: This is an alternative method for coding the on-click event listener. In effect this dodges the problem, leaving the original problem unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think this might answer your question: [Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its the event that's not firing and not a problem launching the intent?

add `log.d("Mytest","OnClick Fired!!!");` as the first line in onClick, then see if you get your message in the debug log.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to set clickable and forcusable property to the row layout.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //Inflate view ....

      button1.setOnClickListener(onclickListener);    
      convertView.setClickable(true);
      convertView.setFocusable(true);
      return converView;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this 
use this

```
 (new OnClickListener(){....
```

instead of this

```
(new View.OnClickListener(){....
```

here is code...

```
 ((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnPickContact)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ONLINE_ID, (String)v.getTag(TAG_ONLINE_ID));
                act.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        });
```