# Fancy dynamic list in Android: TableLayout vs ListView

Tags: android, listview, tablelayout, android-arrayadapter

There is a requirement to have not-so-trivial dynamic list, each record of which consists of several columns (texts, buttons). It should look something like:

```
Text11 Text12 Button1 Button2
Text21 Text22 Button1 Button2
...
```

At first obvious way to accomplish that seemed to be `TableLayout`. I was expecting to have layout/styling data specified in res/layout/*.xml and to populate it with some dataset from java code (as with `ListView`, for which its possible to specify `TextView` of item in *.xml and bind it to some array using `ArrayAdapter`). But after playing for a while, all I found to be possible is fully populating `TableLayout` programatically. Still, creating `TableRow` by `TableRow` and setting layout attributes directly in java code doesn't seem elegant enough.

**So the question is:** am I at the right path? Is `TableLayout` really best View to accomplish that? Maybe it's more appropriate to extend `ListView` or something else to meet such requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ListView and ArrayAdapter you can do more complicated layouts than just a TextView. You could specify a LinearLayout with 2 TextViews and 2 Buttons for each row in the List.

here's a similar question
[Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

Comment: Because of your answer I reconsidered ListView and I've managed to make it work as required, thanks.

Comment: Still this doesn't answer the question. Is it possible to populate TableLayout with ArrayAdapter

Comment: @Nayn - Of course it's *possible*. Is it worth the effort, rather than just using the right tool for the job (ListView)? Probably not, so James' answer satisfies the question.

Comment: ListView is a great way to implement a list of items that use an Adapter, but it's not always possible to use it (oh how much I wish it weren't the case).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it depends on the amount of your data you need to render.

Build layout dinamically via inflate/addView is a quite simple task but is 
also more slow than using a custom adapter. with a custom adapter you can 
reuse the convertView parameter and then set the values more efficiently