# Problem registering clicks on Button on CustomCursorAdapter in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, button, onclick

What i am trying to do is catch a Button click that is inside a ListView managed by a CustomCursorAdapter. when clicked i need to make the button invisible and update a value in the database. here is the code i am using for the ListActivity and the CursorAdapter.

```
public class MainTabView extends ListActivity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    fillListData();
}


private void fillListData(){
 DataBaseNamesHelper myDbNamesHelper = new DataBaseNamesHelper(this);
 myDbNamesHelper.openDataBase();
 Cursor cursor = myDbNamesHelper.getCursorQueryWithAllTheTaxiStations();
 startManagingCursor(cursor);
   // the desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { DataBaseNamesHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DataBaseNamesHelper.COLUMN_PEOPLE};
    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data as well as the layout information
    CustomCursorAdapter mAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_entry, cursor, columns, to);
    // set this adapter as your ListActivity's adapter
    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);   
    this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(mAdapter);
    myDbNamesHelper.close();

}
```

and the Adapter:

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer,Filterable,
     android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private Context context;
private int layout;
private AlphabetIndexer alphaIndexer;

public CustomCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    alphaIndexer=new AlphabetIndexer(c, c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseNamesHelper.COLUMN_NAME), " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    Cursor c = getCursor();

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

    int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseNamesHelper.COLUMN_NAME);

    String name = c.getString(nameCol);

    /**
     * Next set the name of the entry.
     */
    TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
    if (name_text != null) {
        name_text.setText(name);
    }

    int favCol = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseNamesHelper.COLUMN_FAVOURITED);
    int fav = c.getInt(favCol);

    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    if(fav==1){
     button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

    int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseNamesHelper.COLUMN_NAME);

    String name = c.getString(nameCol);

    /**
     * Next set the name of the entry.
     */
    TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
    if (name_text != null) {
        name_text.setText(name);
    }
    int favCol = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseNamesHelper.COLUMN_FAVOURITED);
    int fav = c.getInt(favCol);

    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    Log.e("fav",String.valueOf(fav));
    if(fav==1){
     button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

 @Override
 public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
  return alphaIndexer.getPositionForSection(section);
 }

 @Override
 public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return alphaIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
 }

 @Override
 public Object[] getSections() {
    return alphaIndexer.getSections();
 }
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  Log.e("item Click", arg1.toString()+ " position> " +arg2);
 }
```

i have already set the button to be clickable(true) and focusable(false).

with this code i can achieve what i want but by clicking the listView row (logs only item clicks on the LinearLayout that is holding the button. how do i make the button receive click exactly the same as LinearLayout does?

here is the row layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:focusable="false">
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/name_entry"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="28dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
       <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Fav" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:focusable="false" android:clickable="true"></Button><TextView
  android:id="@+id/number_entry"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="28dip" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a new aproach as is this described in the [button documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

However, instead of applying an OnClickListener to the button in your activity, you can assign a method to your button in the XML layout, using the android:onClick attribute. For example:

```
<Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

Now, when a user clicks the button, the Android system calls the activity's selfDestruct(View) method. In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter. For example:

```
 public void selfDestruct(View view) {
     // Kabloey
 }
```

The View passed into the method is a reference to the widget that was clicked. You can `setTag()` on the View in the adapter to recognize which button was clicked.

Comment: yes i already tried that but the problem in that case was that i didn't know the position of the clicked item in the list. i just found an post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons. Now i set a onClickListener to the button in my adapter and set its tag to be the _id of the column row. so now i can make it work. basically your answer is the exact same alternative. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line in your item layout xml file. This should be added to the root layout.

```
<LinearLayout .....
              android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
              ..... />
```

From there you can set your onClickListener of the button in the getView method of your adapter.