# How get position of child inside listview?

Tags: android, listview, view

In code below, how get `Button` position of clicked button?

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
Button button;
TextView text;

public HistoryAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(final Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.historylist, parent, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    text.setText(body);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work (the `final` is important):

```
    @Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    final int position = cursor.getPosition();
    text.setText(body);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doSomething(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: why final important here ?

Comment: `final` is mandatory to use the value in the onClickListener, when it will be created the listener consider the value will not changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the position of the item in the list, you can access it from the View passed to the onClick method, referring to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541821/get-listview-item-position-on-button-click) you can edit the code doing:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    text.setText(body);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
        }
    });
}
```

hope it works :)

Comment: this CursorAdapter used for listview , i want get position of button in list view if it clicked

Comment: While links may answer the question, it is not advisable to post them. Post the relevant code from the links that you think will solve the problem and add the links as a reference. In future, the links might get modified or replaced, making the answer totally irrelevant. Also, certain links are not accessible to everyone.