# How to pass button position inside listview to another activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-button

Like the title, if I press a button inside the listview I want that send the position of the button to another activity

I don't know what code do you want to check what I did.

I put the method when the button is pressed, this method is inside the listadapter

```
   listHolderRiepilogo.btnNota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext() ,Pop_Nota.class);
            i.putExtra("posizione", ---WHAT TO PUT HERE---);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is it a listview or recyclerview ?

Comment: You can make use of button.setTag(position) function inside listener and while retrieving call Integer.parseInt(button.getTag())

Comment: i don't know how to use the setTag() in this case, i haven't nothing to put inside ()

Comment: First inside listview listener write setTag() function so that you can retrieve value in button click listener

Comment: Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29980698/2308683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
make position of getView method final and send it in intent

 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
      listHolderRiepilogo.btnNota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext() ,Pop_Nota.class);
            i.putExtra("posizione", position);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i did what you said but when i pass the value it seem to be ->  null

Comment: check the spelling for putextra string and getextra in the next activity are they matching?

Comment: it's works, in the next activity i put String instead of int.