# Get ListView text and position on button click

Tags: android, listview, button, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I know this question was asked 4 years ago, but none of the answers helped me. I am following along in a book (Apress's Android Pro 5) trying to get this project to work. However, the mandatory book is outdated.

I have a simple [ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuaNK.png) with a button on the bottom. Each list view item has a checkbox next to it.  When the button is clicked it should say "ListView  is checked at position ".

Everything loads, visually, just fine. But, when I follow the book's instructions, the button does nothing. When I follow any instructions from the [Get listview item position on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541821/get-listview-item-position-on-button-click) article, the application crashes when the button is clicked. Please note, my code below is everything I have. There aren't any other methods or anything else. Here is my code:

//Main part of code setting things up

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView1;
private Button button1;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String[] someColors = new String[]{"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", 
    "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet", "Black", "White"};

    ArrayList<String> colorArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    colorArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(someColors));

    listAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, colorArrayList);

    listView1.setAdapter(listAdapter1);
```

//Add the checkboxes

```
    listView1.setChoiceMode(listView1.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

//Here is the onItemClickListener for the list view

```
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
    position, long id) {
            String itemValue = (String) 
    listView1.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemValue, 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

//Here is the action that is not responding at all. It literally does not make anything happen when run.

```
public void doClick(View view) {
    int count = listView1.getCount();

    SparseBooleanArray viewItems = listView1.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(viewItems.get(i)){
            String selectColor = (String)listView1.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Log.v("List View", selectColor + "is checked at position" + i);
        }
    }

}
```

And for good measure, here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="492dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:text="@string/sub"
        android:onClick="doClick"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines from

```
@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int
position,long id){
        String itemValue = (String)
                listView1.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemValue,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

To

```
@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int
position,long id){
        String itemValue = colorArrayList.get(position);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemValue,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Good news, the change doesn't crash the app, and the items are still popping up with their name when checked. However, the button still isn't responding; nothing at all happens when the button is clicked, except the button animation. Thoughts?

Comment: The button is not supposed to do anything except print log. Check your logcat after clicking button