# Using camera intent in ListView send the position and Get the position in OnActivtyResult method

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I have a Listview and TakePicture button event for each list item. I need to send position and get position back on OnActivityResult method to Update Image to List Item using that position

My code is

```
holder.TakePicture1.Click += delegate (object sender, System.EventArgs args)
  {
     if (remnantModel != null)
        {
           Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
           camIntent.PutExtra("Position", position);
           context.StartActivityForResult(camIntent, 2);
         }
  };
```

In OnActivityResult function

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
  {
       base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch (requestCode)
        {
        case 2:
            if (data != null)
            {
                Bundle extras = data.Extras;
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)extras.Get("data");
                int pos = data.GetIntExtra("position", 0);
                int position = data.Extras.GetInt("position", 0); 
                // Not getting position value here
                RemList[pos].Path.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap); 
            }
        }
  }
```

As above code, I am using native ActionImageCapture event and not able to get Position in OnActivityResult function.

How can I get data i.e position in OnActivityResult method?

Comment: Hello, have you checked my answer?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT thank you for your feedback. yeah I worked on using static varilable, I am not getting accurate position when hit click event in a list.

Comment: That means when you click item 2, it will show position 4? If so, I guess you need handle the reuse problem. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541821/get-listview-item-position-on-button-click), use Tag to handle the reuse problem.

Comment: Hi, have you solved it?

Comment: Yes, I make it happen by passing position to static variable on click event and by seeing getview method by not calling multiple times

Answer (score 0):

> get data i.e position in OnActivityResult method

You can't get the position in `OnActivityResult` by your code.

1) it should be `Position`, not `position`.

2) if you change it to `Position` (`data.GetIntExtra("Position", 0);`), you still can't get the position.

About `StartActivityForResult` method:

If you want to jump from `AcitivityA` to `AcitivityB` without return value, you can use `StartActivity`, but if you want to get data from `AcitivityB`, you need to use `StartActivityForResult`, and at the same time, you need to use [SetResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android/10407371#10407371) method in the **SystemCameraAcitvity**, there is a problem, we can't handle the **SystemCameraAcitvity**, it is system activity, we don't have the Activity in our application, so we can't use `SetResult` to send the position back to our activity which contains the `ListView`.

So, the solution is that, you need to define a static variable in your activity to store the position, change its value when you click the button, and after taking the picture, you need to judge the `resultCode` and `requestCode`, and then, use the static variable to set the picture.