# How can I perform onListItemClick in a list view on android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListView` with three `ImageButton`s and `TextView`s, `ImageView`. How can I perform `onListItemClick` in a `ListView` for individual actions for each `ImageButton`.

```
public class AndroidThumbnailList extends ListActivity{
    ..........
    ib2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    ib3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    ib1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
            public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,String[] objects) {
                    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                     .........
            }
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        Log.e("video", "called");
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(v.equals(ib1)){
             ....
        } 
        if(v.equals(ib2)){
             ....
        }

   }
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(AndroidThumbnailList.this, R.layout.row,  _videosId));
   }

}
```

If I touch `ImageButton no action is done and the`ImageButton`s also not highlighted.

my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"      android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<image view>....</image view>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1 ... ></ImageButton>
 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton2 ... ></ImageButton>
 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton3 ... ></ImageButton>
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set individuals `onClick()` event handlers for each `ImageButton`.

You have to declare the method of your context (typically, your `Activity`):

```
public void onClickHandler(View v)
```

See Javadocs of [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) and [onClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) for further details.

Comment: i implement as follows: i get null pointer exception please help me
class implement OnclickListener{
  ib1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image1);
  ib1.setOnclickListener(this);  // null pointer exception
  
  public void onClickHandler(View v){
      if(v.getid.equals(R,id.image){...}  
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set listener to each `Button` in `getView()` of `ListAdapter`.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons).

Comment: ohh i missed it. you were faster. +1 for that.                        My answer: same as this one.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using `ListView` or `LinearLayout`? `ListActivity` is used along with `ListView`, I don't see yours. You have used LinearLayout instead and have given your own `ImageButton`s, which are not created by the adapter, thus not using `onListItemClick`.

Second (this is just opinion, you can make it work without that), IMHO, you better define `OnClickListener` when you define your items in `getView()`, and not using `onListItemClick`.