# How to interact with buttons present in list view

Tags: android, listview, button, onclick

I have created an `customListview` where i have inserted an button..now on click of that `button` i want to start new `activity`..how that can be done the code for creating `custom listview` is given below..can anyone tell me how i interact with that button to start a new `activity`..

code:

```
public static class ViewHolder
{
    Button butAddNew;
    TextView txtViewHeading;
    TextView  txtViewTitle;
    TextView  txtViewDescription;

}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.histryfrm_listview, null);
        holder.butAddNew =(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.butAddNew);
        holder.txtViewTitle =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
        holder.txtViewDescription =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescription);
        holder.txtViewHeading =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewHeading);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);
    holder.txtViewHeading.setText(heading[position]);
    return convertView;
} 
}
```

Comment: please post your histryfrm_listview.xml.. thats what i'm asking..

Comment: on bottom of your question u will options to edit, retag etc there click on edit and just paste your code,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always send a onClickListener from your Activity to your adapter when you create it.

Otherwise set a listener in your adapter or by using the onClick in the xml of the item.

When I did similar things I passed my activities onclicklistener to my adapter.

Edit: 
Examples:

http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Or better:

[Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

It all depends on how you will do it. 
But the other answer will probably work, just pass the correct context.

Comment: how that can be done can you please explain me with an example.

Comment: Added two links with examples.

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple set  `holder.butAddNew.setOnClickListener` in getView like as

```
holder.butAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent code for Start Activity
            }
        });
```

create constructor of your customeadapter class and pass activity or context in that constructor and use that for start activity.

updated

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 

{
    ViewHolder holder;

if(convertView==null)
{
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.histryfrm_listview, null);
    holder.butAddNew =(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.butAddNew);
    holder.txtViewTitle =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
    holder.txtViewDescription =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescription);
    holder.txtViewHeading =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewHeading);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else
    holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);
holder.txtViewHeading.setText(heading[position]);
holder.butAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Context, activity.class));
            }
        });

return convertView;
}
```

Comment: But inside how i can call another activity..thats what i want.

Comment: i have updated it in my code but it  show error in startActivity..i have just send you the updated code..

Comment: first check did you add your new activity in menifest and second thing is pass proper context in intent like as getBaseContext() or getApplicationContext();

Comment: and what about context? did u passed proper context?

Answer (score 1):

u need to do something like this..

```
public static class ViewHolder
    {
        Button butAddNew;
        TextView txtViewHeading;
        TextView  txtViewTitle;
        TextView  txtViewDescription;

    }
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.histryfrm_listview, null);
        holder.butAddNew =(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.butAddNew);
        holder.txtViewTitle =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
        holder.txtViewDescription =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescription);
        holder.txtViewHeading =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewHeading);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);
    holder.txtViewHeading.setText(heading[position]);
    return convertView;
} 

    @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
            LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) listView.getChildAt(position);
                    //your code
                    //even this works fine if u don't have too many buttons
                      //u can call your activity here
```

}

Comment: IS button text means button id

Comment: please i am not able to get it i will send you the entire code you check it where i have to use it..just wait