# ListView clicklisteners

Tags: android, listview

I have a `list view` which has a couple of views within it, I have a `textView` and an `ImageView`.

What I need to do is, I want a person to be able to click just on the `imageView` without causing the `onItemClicked` function to be invoked, If the person clicks the `ImageView`, it should do something else, but if the person clicks away(apart from the `imageview`) from the `imageView`, then the `onItemClicked` is fired.

How do I do this?

It is kinda like, the `listView` on the android phone `callLogs` whereby, the green phone icon is somehow separated from the list but when clicked, it should know which `listItem` was selected and act accordingly.

I will appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: It really depends on your implementation .. So show us your code and tell me when you edit

Comment: This is all over SO... did you search?

Comment: I thought google.com is famous site :O

Comment: ingsaurabh, I thot so, trgraglia:hence the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links for you are looking for. Advanced but if you stick with it and dont give up on this, you will learn a ton!!! Take a look:

[Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

[Android custom list item with nested widgets](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-wit)

Answer (score 1):

use `holder.imageView.setOnClickListener()` in getView() method of adapter class.