# Custom Listener for a ListView item

Tags: android, listview, listener

I have a View with a `ListView` appended, which actually uses a custom view item done programatically. Inside each list item I have a button which I need to track, to update another item in the view. It is only invalidated when you click on the list item button, not anywhere else in the list item.

So I thought of creating a custom Listener. I trigger it when the button is clicked, **but I have no way to access it from the ListView activity**.

Is there a way to simulate those `setOnItem...Listener`'s using a custom listener? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can you not access it from the ListView activity? Can you post some code? And what do you mean by "a button I need to track"?

Comment: @Jack because I'm not directly getting each item in the list. What I would want is some sort of `itemList.setOnItemButtonClicked...`. However this one is within the ListView, while I need it inside the custom list item view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons/1776328#1776328) link to help with how to set `onClickListener` from within custom `ListAdapters`.

You can use the `myButton.getTag()` and `myButton.setTag()` to put and get data to/from your `View`/`Button`.

See [this](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx) link as well to help with custom `ListAdapters`.
[Here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) is another good example I found of how to use a custom adapter.

Comment: I didn't solve my problem that way, but thanks to your links I kind of managed to do. What I did was event bubbling (in a rudimentary way). I just got the event from the custom view, listened in the adapter and listened again in the list itself. You deserve the points =)