# Why my own ListAdapter does not work?

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, listview-adapter

the problem i have is when i click a chekbox and make the listview scroll-up the selected checkbox change or sometimes if a select the first checkbox so the last checkbox is selected too. I know my English is not good enough yet, sorry about it. Any help appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

     public static class ViewHolder {

         public CheckBox chkb = null;

    } 


    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private ArrayList<MyListAdapterItem> myListAdapterItems = null;

    private Hashtable<Object, Object> items = null;

    private boolean selectAll = false;

    private boolean readOnly = false;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyListAdapterItem> myListAdapterItems, boolean selectAll, boolean readOnly) {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        this.myListAdapterItems = myListAdapterItems;

        this.selectAll = selectAll;

        this.readOnly = readOnly;

        items = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chkb_fila, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.chkb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbCultivo);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        items.put(myListAdapterItems.get(position), viewHolder.chkb);

        viewHolder.chkb.setText(myListAdapterItems.get(position).getDescription());

        if(selectAll){

            viewHolder.chkb.setChecked(true);
        }

        if(readOnly){

            viewHolder.chkb.setEnabled(false);

        }

        return convertView;

    }


    public int getCount() {

        return myListAdapterItems.size();

    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return myListAdapterItems.get(position);

    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;

    }

    /**
     * @return the myListItems
     */
    public ArrayList<MyListAdapterItem> getMySelectedListItems() {

        ArrayList<MyListAdapterItem> listSelectedItems = new ArrayList<MyListAdapterItem>();

        CheckBox tmpCheckBox = null;

        for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){

            tmpCheckBox = (CheckBox) items.get(myListAdapterItems.get(i));

            if(tmpCheckBox.isChecked()){

                listSelectedItems.add(myListAdapterItems.get(i));

            }

        }

        return listSelectedItems;

    }

}
```

Comment: _Thanks_ I change the method getView, like this:

Comment: So I save the states of the checkboxes on boolean array: private boolean[] states = null;. Using private Hashtable<CheckBox, Integer> itemsPosiciones = null; to save the reference a Checkboxes, so when one of the change its state i just save the state: states[itemsPosiciones.get((CheckBox)arg0)] = arg1;

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chkb_fila, null);
CheckBox chkb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbCultivo);
chkb.setText(myListAdapterItems.get(position).getDescription());
chkb.setChecked(states[position]);
chkb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
states[itemsPosiciones.get((CheckBox)arg0)] = arg1;
}
});itemsPosiciones.put(chkb, position);return convertView;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `getView` method reuses the views, thus you must make sure to update the checkboxs' states inside that method; that also implies that you must save that state somewhere.

Comment: _Thanks_ I just find a simple way to save the states of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links for you are looking for. Advanced but if you stick with it and dont give up on this, you will learn a ton!!! Take a look:

[Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

[Android custom list item with nested widgets](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-wit)

[Rating bars and buttons on listItems](http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/multicolumn-listview-with-image-icon/)

Answer (score 0):

2 options.

1) Don't recycle your view.  Always inflate a new one.  That's "lazy", but if your app doesn't have too many entries, its less likely to introduce a bug.

2) Make sure you set everything on each view.  You're reusing them, so if you've set something on one previously, it'll stay that way.

Change this:

```
if(selectAll){

        viewHolder.chkb.setChecked(true);
    }

    if(readOnly){

        viewHolder.chkb.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

to

```
        viewHolder.chkb.setChecked(selectAll);
        viewHolder.chkb.setEnabled(!readOnly);
```

With the if blocks, you're not setting the other side of the boolean value (you could also use else blocks, but that's more verbose).