# How to move to another activity when a button inside the ListView is clicked

Tags: android, listview, onclick, baseadapter

How to go to another `Activity` when a `Button` inside the `ListView` is clicked
I have a custom list which I'm inflating it in `getview()` and I'm also made the buttons clickable but how to move to another `Activity` when button pressed.

Answer (score 2):

add this

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick() {
        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

replace OtherActivity with the activity class name that you want to switch to.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to doing this is to add an `OnClickListener` to your button inside the adapter's `getView()` method and to use `getTag()` and `setTag()` to communicate the necessary data to the `OnClickListener`. There's a detailed tutorial [here](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-with-nested.html) about this and also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons) that talks about how it works for multiple buttons in a row.

Comment: @Girish - You should mark this thread as solved. (Click on the check mark next to the answer that provided the solution.)

Answer (score 0):

register your list activity  under application tag in Android Manifest.xml file.