# How to identify different images in a row of a ListView?

Tags: android

I need to implement a UI which displays many images(more than 1000). The layout of the images like this:

```
(image1)  (image2)  (image3)
  ( image4 )    ( image5 )
  ( image6 )    ( image7 )
     ...
  ( imageN )    ( imageN+1)
```

I want to show these images in a ListView and I know how to do that. But, I don't know how to identify which image is clicked after showing them. I need to display a big image after clicking the little image in the ListView. Any answer will be appreciated.

Edit 1: if it is hard for a ListView to do this, is it possible to use a GridView to implement this kind of layout?

Comment: you should have an id for the clicked list item, use that to determine what image it is.

Comment: But the id can be used to identify different rows only, still can't know which image is clicke since there are 2 or 3 image in a row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons - you need to set onclick listeners to each image then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `ArrayList` of `ImageView`, and add all `imageView` objects in it. Then just call `setOnTouchListener` to all elements of the arraylist using loop. In the `OnTouch(View v, MotioNEvent event)` method, the View v is your `imageView`.

for example:

```
for(int i=0;i<imageArray.size();i++){
    imageArray.get(i).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        protected boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            //v is your image on which the touch event happened.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: All the imageViews are managed by the ListAdapter, so I add an OnClickeListener for each imageViews in the function getView(...) of the ListAdapter. But when I click the image nothing happens. Seems the image didn't know it is clicked, what's the problem?

Comment: This is not a problem, the imageViews can know it is clicked after setting the OnClickListener.

Comment: No problem. By the way you can always accept the answer if it worked, so that other readers facing similar problems get to know which solution works best.