# Android listview with multiple controls

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am new to android. I am developing an application in which there is a list view of students with edit and delete buttons. Like

> ---
>
> ```
>  STUDENT LIST
> ```
>
> [ABC]              [edit]              [delete]
>
> [DEF]              [edit]              [delete]
>
> ---

With this code im able to list student details in a `<Textview>`

```
public class DataBaseDemoActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
  SQLiteDatabase db;
  Button btnInsert;
  ArrayAdapter<String> students;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  try{
  db=openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);

  Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM temp",null);
  String[] students = new String[c.getCount()];

  if (c.moveToFirst())
  {                       
      for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++)
      {
          students[i] = c.getString(0).toString()+" "+c.getString(1).toString();
          c.moveToNext();
      }           
  }
  c.close();

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, students));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });


  }catch(SQLException e)
  {
  }
}
```

}

I need to store the id of the record with in the list view so that when i click on the edit or delete button, i'll have to find out the id and make changes on the DB. How can i set values to two fields say `<TextView>`[show details] and `<EditText>`[visibility: insisible - to save id of the record]. I am able to get the details to the `<TextView>` using the above code. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

UPDATE :

Layout i am using

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
    >
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:onClick="showInfo"
        />
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="230dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/studentInfo" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action"
        android:onClick="showInfo"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "id of the record " means database record id with text? M I right?

Comment: @user370305 : i mean id of the database record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Id within cursor data fetch loop, use any `HashMap<id,String>` collection for it and store id along with data (text).

As per your requirement, I suggest you to use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter` with `ListView`.

So you can manage easily your database records with your list and also get the all information related to database for particular record when List Item clicked.

Look at [SimpleCursorAdapters and ListViews](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

[Creating a custom CursorAdapter for Android](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/)

Answer (score 1):

after this line..

```
   students[i] = c.getString(0).toString()+" "+c.getString(1).toString();
    student_ids[i]=Integer.parseInt(//get the  id... )
  //and you dont need to put it in invisible edittext...
```

in onclick method you will get integer "position"..and get tha value in students_ids[] at that position..

```
 int id=students_ids[position];
```

Comment: How will i get integer position when i click on edit button?.. can u please tell..

Comment: is your button not a part of listview's row?

Comment: yes button is within the row. i have updated question.. added my layout. please check.

Comment: [You should use a custom adapter.. see this link](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-with-nested.html) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)