# ListView item with button and know what item the button was inside after click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a list view where items have a text view and a button. I have managed to make list view onclick and button on click work together. The problem is that when I click the button I don't really know what list view item index it belongs too. Is there any way to know that? I need this to pass it to a "CRUD" for editing, etc...

Comment: add the item index in tag of button in getview function

Comment: One solution is setTag() and getTag() otherwise You can check this link so you will get idea and solution 

[List View Button Click][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use setTag and getTag here to get the position of the Button Clicked in the ListView,

Something like,

`button.setTag(position);` // in your getView() method

and then,

`int cur_pos = (Integer)v.getTag();` // inside onClick of Button in getView() method

Comment: Thank you so much! @Prabuddha please do think you could help me here :http://goo.gl/MAjgTh

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

- You can have separate `OnClickListener` instances for each button.
- You can call `setTag()` on your button to store arbitrary data (e.g. index or identifier) and retrieve it later with `getTag()`

Answer (score 1):

An other solution would be to reproduce the button click on its parent, when the user tap on the button:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()