# Getting object out of a ListView with a CustomAdapter android

Tags: android

I've got a custom Adapter like this:

```
public class DeviceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static ArrayList<Device> availableDevices;
Context c;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

/**
 * Constructor for this class
 * @param context Which context triggered this class
 * @param devices Object of each devices
 */
public DeviceAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Device> devices) {
    this.availableDevices = devices; 
    this.c = context; 
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}


public int getCount() {
    return availableDevices.size();
}


public Object getItem(int position) {
    return availableDevices.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.device_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText("Device name: "+availableDevices.get(position).getName());
    holder.address.setText("Mac-address: "+ availableDevices.get(position).getAddress());


    return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView address;

}
```

}

My question is: How can I access an objects variable `name` where the user presses?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243040/how-to-pass-the-value-of-row-in-listview-to-a-button/11243100#11243100

Answer (score 2):

use onItemClickListenerwith list http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

```
ist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
      Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);

     or
     TextView tv =    (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
         name = tv.getText(); 

   } 
});
```

Comment: onItemSelectedListener or onItemClickListener?

Comment: thanks a lot Paresh, I wrote the title right but code of different function by mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can get OnClick event for only name TextView click, by adding holder.name.setOnClickListener.......
See followin code

```
public class DeviceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static ArrayList<Device> availableDevices;
Context c;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

/**
 * Constructor for this class
 * @param context Which context triggered this class
 * @param devices Object of each devices
 */
public DeviceAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Device> devices) {
    this.availableDevices = devices; 
    this.c = context; 
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}


public int getCount() {
    return availableDevices.size();
}


public Object getItem(int position) {
    return availableDevices.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.device_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText("Device name: "+availableDevices.get(position).getName());
    holder.address.setText("Mac-address: "+ availableDevices.get(position).getAddress());

    //   PUT FOLLOWIN   ------------------
    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    put your dezired code here which runs OnClick of TextView NAME
                }
            });
    //         -----------------

    return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView address;

}

}
```

Comment: You should include only the required code here. It looks good as well.

Comment: Dear Paresh, I have put all code, because Tobias Moe Thorstensen can know where to add the extra code

Comment: Yup Paresh, but I thought Tobias Moe Thorstensen is newer(reputation-159), so I made my hint easier. If Tobias Moe Thorstensen doesn't know that the code given by Dheeresh must be putted in the Activity which is using DeviceAdapter adapter class, then Dheeresh's effort may be lesser useful to Tobias Moe Thorstensen.