# Android GridView with two different items?

Tags: android, gridview, memory-leaks

I’ve got a GridView which i should fill with two different items such as left_item and right_item. Anyway, i wrote a custom adapter extended from BaseAdapter.

And i saw converted views were not in ordered how i thought. So i was seeing my GridView like this:

```
Left    Right
Right   Left
Left    Right
Left    Right
Right   Left
…       …
```

And so on. I’ve found a solution this to order as well. But my question is if my solution is a right way to approach this problem or not? Here’s my Custom Adapter and my solution:

```
class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // return even count in any case
    public int getCount() {
        if (items.size() % 2 == 0)
            return items.size();
        else
            return (items.size() + 1);
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        // Here, i thought that i was gonna have 
        // converted views one left one right, but i didn't!
        if (v == null) {
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                // inflate left side
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_shelf_item, null);
            } else {
                // inflate right side
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_shelf_item, null);
            }
        }

        if (position % 2 == 0) {

          // So i had to inflate left view, if i'm not getting that
            if(v.getId() != R.layout.left_shelf_item)
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_shelf_item, null);

            if (position != items.size()) {
                ImageView img = (ImageView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.leftShelfItemBook);
                if (img != null) {
                    int bookId = Integer.parseInt(items.get(position)
                            .getBookId());
                    if (images.get(bookId) != null) {
                        img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(images
                                .get(bookId)));
                    } else {
                        img.setImageDrawable(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

          // And here, i do the same for right
            if(v.getId() != R.layout.right_shelf_item)
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_shelf_item, null);

            if (position != items.size()) {
                ImageView img = (ImageView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.rightShelfItemBook);
                if (img != null) {
                    int bookId = Integer.parseInt(items.get(position)
                            .getBookId());
                    if (images.get(bookId) != null) {
                        img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(images
                                .get(bookId)));
                    } else {
                        img.setImageDrawable(null);
                    }
                }
            } else if (position == items.size()) {
                ((View) v.findViewById(R.id.rightShelfItemHolder))
                        .setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

As you see, i forced adapter to use correct view by inflating views again if they’re not the ones they’re supposed to be.

Because of this, i’m very concern of having memory leak and getting OutOfMemoryError, or some other errors caused by inflating too much.

Is there any other way to achieve this? I need a better solution, please. 
Any help or information would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason to use namely GridView for exactly 2 columns, other layouts might be an alternative. Say, TableLayout.

Comment: But i'll have lots of images, so i cannot use TableLayout because as i know it has not converted view logic?? I can't keep every image on memory, that will certainly cause outofmemory.

Comment: How about ListView with the left/right parts right in the layout? At least, seems to be able to reduce the number of inflation calls.

Comment: But in listView, i cannot click them one by one?

Comment: I think you can: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1776328/1665128