# Complex dynamic tables/lists

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

This is a questionnaire like app, with groups, each group contains several questions, each question contains several operations/answers.

For example:

```
---------------------------------------------------
Group 1
---------------------------------------------------
Question       |   Y/N/NA   | Action   | Completed Y/N
---------------------------------------------------
Question    1A |   Dropdown | EditText | Checkbox
Description 1A |
---------------------------------------------------
Question    1B |   Dropdown | EditText | Checkbox
Description 1B |
---------------------------------------------------
Question    1C |   Dropdown | EditText | Checkbox
Description 1C |


---------------------------------------------------
Group 2
---------------------------------------------------
Question       |   Y/N/NA   | Action   | Completed Y/N
---------------------------------------------------
Question    2A |   Dropdown | EditText | Checkbox
Description 2A |
---------------------------------------------------
Question    2B |   Dropdown | EditText | Checkbox
Description 2B |
---------------------------------------------------
Question    2C |   Dropdown | EditText | Checkbox
Description 2C |
```

.............
.............

```
---------------------------------------------------
Group N
---------------------------------------------------
Question       |   Y/N/NA   | Action   | Completed Y/N
---------------------------------------------------
Question    NA |   Dropdown | EditText | Checkbox
Description NA |
---------------------------------------------------
Question    NB |   Dropdown | EditText | Checkbox
Description NB |
---------------------------------------------------
Question    NC |   Dropdown | EditText | Checkbox
Description NC |
```

Because the groups and questions could be changed anytime so I would like to make the layout dynamic.

I tried to customize BaseAdaptor with Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1 but it can handle simple layout, and only for 1 table.

How to make a dynamic layout with multiple tables/lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ExpandableListView`, it could be abit more flexible to you to customise. Each parent represent a group, and its children represent the question and answer. You can look up here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be broken into 2 parts -

1. how to create sub lists and
2. how to customize each cell within a list.

To create sub lists with header, you can try something like [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/). It adds section headers for each sub list.

To customize each cell, you can inflate view for cell as described in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

Hope this helps.