# Button in ListView and OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

this time i just got no point how 2 go further down the Rabbit Hole.
i got ListView with custom adapter and button on it, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView4"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
   android:textColor="#f16b7f" />

  <Button
   android:id="@+id/describe"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/describe"
   android:focusable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

on Fragment where that ListView is looks like

```
@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rewards_list,
        container, false);
    ListView rewardsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.rewardsList);
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    rewardAdapter = new RewardAdapter(context, movies);
    rewardsList.setAdapter(rewardAdapter);
    rewardsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            mListener.onRewardSelected(arg2);
        }
    });
    return view;
  }
```

what i want to do is let user click only button on adapter and only on click it call

```
mListener.onRewardSelected(arg2);
```

and i got no idea how

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread seems like it dealt with the same problem and found a solution?

[Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

Comment: yea thanks, I read it several times before, but this time i found solution in that, after little change ofc :)