# Android Custom Layout for listview

Tags: android, listview

I am using a list view as follows

```
String[] Shows = new String[] { "Dexter", "Breaking Bad", "The Big Bang Theory", "Leverage"};
ListView tv_show_list = (ListView) view_tvshowAddNew.findViewById(R.id.lv_tv_show_list);

ArrayAdapter<String> showNameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.tv_show_each_show_name, Shows);

tv_show_list.setAdapter(showNameAdapter);
```

Now my tv_show_each_show_name XML is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 

    > 
</TextView>
```

What I want to do now is make each show name associated with a picture and maybe put that in a map, like :-

```
Map mMap = new HashMap();
mMap.put("Dexter", "imageDexter.png");
mMap.put("Breaking Bad", "imageDexter.png");
```

and while loading the list view i will show the name from this map and set the associated image background taking the image name from this map and loading it from the drawable folder.

How to do this?

Hopping like a layout as follows

[image]

Comment: I believe this is rather pertinent: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [Adding 2 buttons to the text view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609296/adding-2-buttons-to-the-text-view/19609481#19609481)
You basically need a custom adapter for your list and need to override the getView method of it, where you can specify the item's UI layout.

For the code you've posted, instead of using an instance of ArrayAdapter, create your own adapter derived from ArrayAdapter
YourData should be a class to contain reference to item's text and item's image.

Now override the getView method in your custom Adapter class.
The method is used to populate the UI for an item using the position argument from

View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

You can get that item using ArrayAdapter.getItem

For more details refer to the link above and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: I am new to android development. I need more detail. can u elaborate your answer? thank you

Answer (score 0):

look at this example [here](http://javatechig.com/android/asynchronous-image-loader-in-android-listview/) it shows how to load the images in listview in android,you need to extends the BaseAdapter to create the custom Adapter