# Displaying subitem under the item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have created a `ListView` that is displaying the items perfectly. But I want to display subitem with each item of `ListView`.

How can I do that?

**my code:**

```
public class ListDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
    public static ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_display);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewItems);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);
        ListDisplay.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Custom Layout for listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615766/android-custom-layout-for-listview)

Comment: There are many examples of having a custom layout in a `ListView` in Stackoverflow. Please try searching for one first.

Comment: Note: You don't need `static` variables here. (Also, it isn't good practice to use them in Android)

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution for your question is the Expandable ListView, with this component you can do a listview where every element in that list contains a multiple elements inside.
I let you a link with an example.

[Expandable Listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

If you need some more custom help with your code, we can help you if you post a situation more detailed.

Comment: I'm wouldn't go as far as an ExpandableListView. It sounds like only a custom View that is more complex than `toString`-ing all the data is wanted.