# How to insert 2 or more attribute of .mp3 file in ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to display song title, song album in the ListView and use the song path to play the song by the use of MediaPlayer class. All the attributes has been fetch from the EXTERNAL_STORAGE by the getMusic(),whose return type is String_Array. and title, album and path of all the song has been stored in 3 array respectively.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview1" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private String[] mMusicList;
String hey="2222";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

    mMusicList = getMusic();

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            try {

                playSong(mMusicList[arg2]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private String[] getMusic() {
  final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, 
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA ,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM}, null, null,
            "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

    int count = mCursor.getCount();
    String[] songs = new String[count];
    String[] path=new String[count];
    String[] album=new String[count];
    int i = 0;
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            songs[i] = mCursor.getString(0);
            path[i]=mCursor.getString(1);
            album[i]=mCursor.getString(2);
            i++;
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mCursor.close();
    return path;
}

private void playSong(String path1) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalStateException, IOException {

    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path1);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
  }
}
```

In the code you can see that how all things are going, plz help me out to display all attribute of a songs [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjgYQ.png), current output which i am getting is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rbCv.jpg), if there is any way to display the image of song then plz tell that to.

If there is any other alternative to do this just tell me I am new to android development.

Thank You...

Comment: You can write a custom adapter to display rows according to your requirement. To give you a headstart you can use [this](http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial) tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Custom Layout for listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615766/android-custom-layout-for-listview)