# How can individual item colors be changed upon addition in a listview based on variables in a void function?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on an app that interacts with a Bluetooth device.  The Bluetooth device sends a string of data that includes signal strength, pass/fall test results, and device ID, separated by spaces.  I have a void function that decodes the string of data and adds the decoded string to an ArrayList, puts the decoded data into appropriate variables, and puts the most recent data into a different textView.  I want to change the textView color depending on the results of the "passed" variable decoded from the Bluetooth string.  I want to also change the listView items' colors according to their pass/fail results, but every method I've tried changes all of the items in the listView, or causes my app to crash.

How do I individually change listView colors of the items based on decoded data from a different void function?

These chunks of code are from inside my java activity:
from onViewCreated:

```
mReadingLog  = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanLogView);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_layout, R.id.testResults, listItems) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                listItemShow = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.testResults);

                if(didPass==1){
                    listItemShow.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }else {
                    listItemShow.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }


                return view;
            }
        };//9/11/17
```

from my decoding function:

```
  listItems.add(
            "Device: " + mConnectedDeviceName +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Timestamp: " + currentDateandTime +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Location: " + latitude + " (lat) / " + longitude + " (lon)" +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Phone id: "  + telephonyManager.getDeviceId() +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Valid:" + (passed ? "YES" : "NO") +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "Values: " + "T" + v1 + " / " + v2 +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                   // "=========================" +
                    System.getProperty("line.separator"));//9/11/17


    clickCounter++;//9/11/17


    mShowData.setText(saveData); //kg 8/25/17
    if(passed == true) {
        mShowData.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        didPass = 1;

    } else if (passed == false){
        mShowData.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        didPass = 0;


    } else {
        mShowData.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//9/11/17
```

listview_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="15dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testResults"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

view_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/viewList"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_holder"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/flipperReturn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Return"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_clear_log"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/clear_log"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listview_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/button_holder"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/scanLogView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:divider="@android:color/black"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:maxLines="4096"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This isn't the only method I've tried.  I also followed other questions such as these:

1. Method shown, still changed all of the items at once [here](http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-alternate-list.html)
2. Adding a second textview to my xml file with its own ID and different background colors, and then conditionally setting the arrayAdapter to the appropriate ID.  It still changed all of the contents to the same color but this time the color never changed
3. Moving the arrayadapater and following declarations inside the decoding function.  This caused a crash.
4. Using boolean variables, still change the entire listview instead of individual items
5. Using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1 instead of custom listviews.

What am I doing wrong?  Does anyone have a link to a tutorial that describes how to do this?  I checked all the replies below but nothing I implemented worked as described or really had the same problem that I am having.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615766/android-custom-layout-for-listview

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse is there anyway to do this without creating a custom listview?  I just started learning java programming creating a custom listview is something entirely new for me and it seems to be pretty far out of my range of capabilities

Comment: @KyleG, my very first ListView used a Cursom adpater, they are not really that difficult and they do provide great flexibility such as changing colours based upon content. e.g. I have `int numberrequired = csr.getInt(shoplist_numbertoget_offset) - csr.getInt(shoplist_done_offset);` then a little later `if (numberrequired < 1 ) {
            productname.setTextColor(white);
            productcost.setTextColor(white); ...` this is in `initView`

Comment: @MikeT thanks for the help.  I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) of ArrayAdapter.

Derive a class from ArrayAdapter, implement getView to return a slightly different view based on your needs and use your new ArrayAdapter class.

Comment: Using getView requires creating a custom layout, correct?

Comment: Yes, but it can be as simple as a label in a horizontal layout.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I was hoping there would be another way around making a custom layout just because this is not really essential to the functionality of my app, just something extra and my abilities are pretty limited right now

Comment: I followed the getview guideline [here](https://www.android-examples.com/change-listview-item-text-color-android-programmatically/) to try to keep things simple and it works with changing the background color, but I want to conditionally change the background color based on a variable based on a variable found in a different function.  Is this still the correct way to go?

Comment: Yes, that example is good. In the getView code you will somehow have to add data/and or code to allow you to compute the color. for example if it were odd/even rows you could compute that. Or you might have to add data to the array that backs the ArrayAdapter to indicate which color each component should b.

Comment: I tried introducing a boolean variable into my function that decodes the data but when I added an if statement with the example code but it changes the background at weird times.  I asked another question because I thought this was a separate topic but it got downvoted to hell.  Thanks for the help though

Comment: If I add the boolean variable passed to my arraylist, can I use that variable in getView to set the color?