# How do you have a Button inside a list item in a ListView return the correct object in a BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button, android-adapter

I have a `ListView` which is populated by my SearchResultAdapter that extends `BaseAdapter`.

Each list item has a `Button` and when a button is pressed, I want to know how to return the corresponding object from `List<SearchResult>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the position argument from your `BaseAdapter`'s (SearchResultAdapter's) `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    myButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);

    final SearchResult searchResult = getItem(position)

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           // do something with this search result ...
        }
    }
}
```

And make sure you override your BaseAdapter's `getItem()`:

```
@Override
public SearchResult getItem(int position) {

    return searchResults.get(position);
}
```

Notice that the way `getItem()` is implemented ensures that each position in your list relates to its corresponding item in your searchResults ArrayList.  So position 0 in your list corresponds to object 0 in searchResults, position 1 in your list corresponds to object 1 in searchResults, etc.

In other words, getItem() creates a 'map' between the rows in your list and your underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add in your SearchResultAdapter getView() method a setOnClickListener() for the buttons you're using.

Any data associated with the button has to be added with myButton.setTag() in the getView() method and can be accessed in the onClickListener via view.getTag(). You can also access the position of the item.

You can use the position in order to get the appropriate element from your List.
Here you can find a simple tutorial/overview: [Link](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-with-nested.html)