# Access ListView adapter Button on Main Activity

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

I have a custom listview adapter (Make a separate class for listview adapter) and custom Listview adapter having two button.

Now i want to access these button on my Main Activity and implement  on click listener.

Please suggest me how I can do this?

Comment: Ideally this not right way to do so you do same thing in adapter whatever you wan to do in activity.

Comment: Following this thread will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons

Comment: in to the adapter u can define click event of listview buttan

Comment: if u r doing code and posting and error than some one slove your problem