# ListView items not clickable (event with focusable=false)

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have a ListView that contains an imageview, a textview, and a checkbox. The rows became unclickable when I added the imageview. I have tried many solutions I found including `android:focusable="false"`, `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` and `android:clickable=true`.

Here is my ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:clickable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgListView"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the activity using it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FolderActivity" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstFolders"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:divider="#FFFFFF">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I just need the rows to be clickable again like they were before.

PS: I alreadu had the same problem when I first added the checkbox and solved it with `android:focusable="false"`.

Answer (score 1):

We need the following changes to allow item click on listview to work by avoiding click/focus on the components of the listview items.

1. Add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the
   item layout.
2. Add android:focusableInTouchMode="false" on the
   components inside listview item(example, imageview, button,
   checkbox, textview, custom view, canvas)
3. Return false on the
   event listners on the custom view (example: class that extends
   View implements View.OnTouchListener and the method public boolean
   onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) should return false.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write the on click listener for each of these views inside your adapter's getview method.
also refer this question
[Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons?lq=1).
As even i had had the same issue and in my experience that xml parameter works if you have only one element that is clickable in listview, for multiple ones i wrote it inside the adapter only.