# List View onItemClick is not working

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I have a Custom List View. Each row of the list view contains a checkbox, 2 text views and an image view. I have been tring to open another activity on click of any row of the list view but the onItemClick is not working at all.

```
public class SavedAddress2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView listView1;
    List<list_addr> rowitems;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.saved_address2);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar3);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        rowitems = new ArrayList<list_addr>();

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addr_list);
        list_addr_adapter adapter = new list_addr_adapter(this,
                R.layout.items_sav_addr2, SavedAddress.rowitems);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,Second.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //...
}
```

Is it because I have a checkbox in the list? Because I have applied the same method for other list view and they work perfectly.

Comment: put this attribute  **android:clickable="true"**  in the listView tag in the xml

Comment: @TomHehir Whatever you just said has already been taken care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try seting your checkbox not focusable, like this:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That worked. But in this if we click the checkbox,nothing happens. Could you tell me a way to that as well?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons) will help you if you want your list item controls have events.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

in your layout xml, add this property to root layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

if the listview has button or sort the the focus is on the item for your case it is the checkbox 
and add this to the checkbox

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: That worked. But in this if we click the checkbox,nothing happens. Could you tell me a way to that as well?

Comment: set the onClick Listener in your adapter class

Comment: the onClick Listener of the CheckBox

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the wrong class context.

> Intent intent = new Intent(**Main.this**,Second.class);
>
> startActivity(intent);

**and your class is SavedAddress2**

change it to

> Intent intent = new Intent(**SavedAddress2.this**,Second.class);
>
> startActivity(intent);

```
public class SavedAddress2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView listView1;
    List<list_addr> rowitems;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.saved_address2);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar3);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        rowitems = new ArrayList<list_addr>();

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addr_list);
        list_addr_adapter adapter = new list_addr_adapter(this,
                R.layout.items_sav_addr2, SavedAddress.rowitems);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,Second.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //...
}
```

Let me know if this works for you !:)