# Want to implement on click listener methods for button of a listview item

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I'm beginner in android. On a list view I have two buttons on each list items. I want to implement click listener for both buttons. so where should i apply on click listener methods for buttons ?

Comment: according to me you should just initialise click listener in getView and take callback in your activity/fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

Comment: Atleast post some code, someone in need of SO points will answer these repeated questions also.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement onclick listener inside adapter for each item of your listView

hope this helps.