# How to make whole ListView clickable

Tags: android, android-listview

How to make the whole ListView clickable and not list items?
I want the whole listview click listener trigger, even when clicking on items.

I tried to make listview items `android:clickable="false"` but without any success

Here is listView

```xml
<ListView
                android:id="@+id/unchecked_items"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and here is ListView item

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:clickable="false">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkBox"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cancel_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.478"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/baseline_clear_24"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your `ListView`?

Comment: So, you don't want to click on items but on the `ListView`?

Comment: I have added, and yes I want to click whole listview, not items.

Comment: Have a look at this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons   Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

In your custom ArrayAdapter overide isEnabled method as following

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

This will disable clicks on listview items.

Comment: Now items aren't editable, but whole listview click listener doesn't trigger when clicking items.

Answer (score 1):

Put in your listview item:

```
android:enabled="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

and add this on your Listview:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```